# Typescript: set variable type in comment

Tags: casting, typescript

is possible to set the type of variable in comment, like this:

```
var v = "str";
/** @var v: Number */
v = 5;
```

and let the "v" accept the number on last row? Without casting. This TS code should be runnable in JavaScript with simple copy&paste.

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? And in general, you should be able to run JS in TypeScript, not the other way around.

Comment: var v: number|string = "str"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to annotate the type of `v` with a comment for TypeScript.

You can compile the typescript and copy and paste the javascript if you like.  Or for experimentation, use a typescript fiddle or the typescript playground, etc.

As @anstarovoyt indicated, the correct typing would perhaps be:

```
var v : number | string = "str";
v = 5;
```

and this would compile back to the unannotated original:

```
var v = "str";
v = 5;
```

Answer (score 9):

Typescript can infer types from JSDOC comments. Something like this

```
/** @type {number} */
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with official TypeScript, and it seems it will not happen in the near future ([Issue #9694](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9694)).

But you can use my fork https://github.com/luciotato/plus-typescript

It is a small hack allowing you to add TypeScript type-annotations within comments:

Example:

```
function ShowHelp(title/*:string*/, options/*:Record<string,OptDecl>*/) /*:void*/ {
  ...
}
```

https://github.com/luciotato/plus-typescript/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/luciotato/plus-typescript

Beta. Maintainers are welcomed